# Nginx www redirect not working for https.

Tags: nginx

```
# nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.2.1
```

I've tried everything I can find
I cannot get the http://www.mysite.com to direct to https://mysite.com.
What I have right now will redirect http://mysite.com to https://mysite.com.
http://www.mysite.com does not work at all.  It returns a **Oops! Google Chrome could not find www.mysite.com** 
Here is my current half working configuration:

### vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.mysite.com;
        return 301 $scheme://mysite.com$request_uri;
}


server {
        listen   443;

        allow all;
        root /home/jacob/mysite;
        server_name mysite.com;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mysite_com.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
        ...
```

No matter what I try, the non www will always work and the www will not work at all. I am not sure if I need to reset something else.  Every time I change the config file I restart the nginx server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `www.` subdomain to point at your server in DNS.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even think of that.